# Can I get back into the USA to visit after overstaying with a new passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas, overstaying

When I first went to the USA it was before fingerprinting, so I was not fingerprinted. I overstayed for 10 months. I came home and then went back to the US and got back in, and this time I was fingerprinted. I overstayed for 3 and a half years. When I left the US, I had a new passport, as if I'd lost my passport in the States.

I'm attempting to go back now for a visit. It has been 10 years since I left the States (my 10-year ban would be over). I'm told I have to apply for a non-immigrant visa, but the chances of getting approval are slim, due to the fact that I have overstayed my welcome on 2 occasions.

I'm from Northern Ireland. I can have two passports: a UK passport or an Irish passport. If I change my passport and attempt to enter, would I be denied? I honestly have no intentions of overstaying again, but I’d love to go back and see some old friends.

Comment: How do you manage to overstay for years?  Independently wealthy?  Or were you taking employ here?  How did you get past the right-to-work checks?

Comment: @Harper: I don't know the answer to that question, but we are talking here about a country that has more than ten million  illegal aliens. It is obviously not that hard.

Comment: Your chances of getting into the USA are slim and none whether you apply for a visa or try to enter via the VWP and last I checked Slim is already out of town. I'd say fuhgeddabout it being a two time overstayer. They will catch the second overstay, then they will dig deeper and probably find the first overstay. You're toast at that point.

Comment: I thought (and may be wrong here) that EU citizens do not require a VISA for the US (except some, Ireland should be fine AFAIK). Does that change anything?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your admissibility or lack thereof depends on your personal circumstances, not on your passport.  Using a different country's passport to apply for a visa, for ESTA, or for admission does not change your history; it only makes it less likely that the US government will connect you to your history if you try to conceal it.

It is still quite likely that they'll connect you to it, however.  First, as you note, they have your fingerprints.  They'll take new ones when you apply for your visa or try to enter under the visa waiver program, and they will probably match your old ones.  Even in the absence of fingerprints, your new passport will match the old one on the name, date of birth, and place of birth.  They may also have a copy of the photograph from your old passport, and they may match it using facial recognition software.

If you apply to enter the US without disclosing your history and they find out, you will probably be found to be inadmissible under [8 USC 1182(a)(6)(C)(i)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_6_C):

> (C)  Misrepresentation
>
> (i)  In general
>
> Any alien who, by fraud or willfully misrepresenting a material fact, seeks to procure (or has sought to procure or has procured) a visa, other documentation, or admission into the United States or other benefit provided under this chapter is inadmissible.

Note the parenthetical "or has sought to procure": Once you've done this, you are inadmissible for life under this part of the law.  There is a waiver available, but the application costs $930 and success is not at all guaranteed.

Rather than risking that, it's probably wiser to apply for a visa and tell the whole story, along with evidence showing why you won't overstay this time, and hope for the best.  You can use either passport.

Comment: Your probably right, although they may not even have any evidence of when I left the country, (I don’t remember them even looking at my passport), if I was asked I couldn’t lie to them. 

Comment: The US doesn't run emigration checks, but that doesn't mean they definitely do not know when you left (e.g. they may know from APIs). Not relevant to your situation, but may be to others: You can view the info DHS hold on your recent (within 5 years) arrivals/departures online: https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home. Whatever that may say, however, "don't commit fraud" is always sound advice.

Comment: @Sarah the US does not examine passports of departing travelers directly.  That is, your memory that no US officer looked at your passport is entirely correct.  the US does take passport information from airlines, however, and uses that to record departures.

Comment: Thanks guys, I’m gonna do the right thing and try with a non-immigrant visa, if I get denied, it wasn’t to be. Thanks for all your advice 

Comment: @Sarah: "although they may not even have any evidence of when I left the country" Them not knowing when you left the country doesn't help you -- when in doubt, the presumption is you overstayed and the burden is on *you* to prove to them that you left on time.

Comment: @user102008 if there's no evidence of her visit whatsoever, there won't be any presumption that she overstayed.

Comment: @phoog "_ went back to the US and got back in, on this occasion I was fingerprinted_" There clearly is evidence of her visit.

Comment: @TripeHound absolutely.  I should have said "...no evidence of her visit before the visa officer or immigration officer..."  That is, the individual who adjudicates the application must be aware of the evidence for the presumption to come into play.