# What are the chances of being able to enter the States after overstaying?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, overstaying, embassies

I overstayed in the USA on 2 occasions. The first time I stayed for 10 months, the second time, 3 years.

10 years have passed, my ban will be over. The next step is to arrange an interview for a non-immigrant visa. I plan to be completely honest about everything.

The problem is, I’m not married and I don’t own any property at home here, to prove that I have ties at home to stop me overstaying again. I do work part-time as a caretaker for a school and own my own online business. I care for my mother, who is quite dependent on me (she will be traveling with me).

I want to visit for a holiday. I’m wondering whether I am wasting my time even thinking about going to an interview. I’m a very nervous person at the best of times, never mind and intense situation like that. It would really devastate me if I was declined.

Has anybody had a similar experience and got a visa approved?

Comment: You asked almost exactly [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111687/can-i-get-back-into-usa-to-visit-after-overstaying-with-a-new-passport) yesterday. Why are you asking again?